# Can we [sqa]sh this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[sqa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqa) (or Software Quality Assurance to their friends)

The excerpt is useless. The questions are all over the map (only 3 or 4 even have it as the subject). This tag is serving no purpose, except for people to ask off-topic questions or throw it in as a "My code is broken" tag.

Comment: You misspelled "squash"...

Comment: Hum... Looks like the tag info is the [first sentence from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance).

Comment: @AndrewMyers You and your "quality assurance"...

Comment: There is also [tag:qa] tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fine with me.  There's only a handful of 'em anyway.

## We should look to close the off-topic ones *first*.

That is, don't remove the tags from *any* of these until we're fairly sure that we have a handful that actually can be salvaged.  All the rest we can simply close and let the system handle, or delete ourselves.

For example, there are a handful here that reference Selenium.  We want to see if those are worth keeping.  If you think they are, edit them into shape, and *then* remove the tag.

### If you're just removing the tag, please... *don't*.  The post needs to be edited too.

It would be best to leave the questions tagged with it so we can strike precisely with what needs to be removed from the site.

**Update:** All questions that once had this tag have now been retagged or deleted.

Comment: All remaining questions are closed (1) or have close votes (4).

Comment: A lot of the Selenium and Watir-related questions kinda disappeared there.  Were they edited into shape?

Comment: no clue, I just came to it and there were only 5 left.

Comment: Looks like RiggsFolly went through and started just removing tags.  On one or two that looked fine, but on the others that may have not been correct.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25116017/1079354) could use some more editing.

Comment: ...Right.  I'm going to do a bit more to clean up from that and be sure that we don't have too many stragglers.

Comment: @Makoto Yes I did, was I a bit quick of the mark on a few? Thought I was fairly careful

Comment: @RiggsFolly:  A few of those should've been edited further than just removing the tag.  We're not going to see those posts anytime soon so it's best to clean 'em up before they're scattered about the winds.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is why we leave the removal of the tag as the last step after everyone has had their fill of closure and deletion of old crap (or editing further than just removing the tag).

Comment: Something learned!

Comment: Agree with everything here regarding the process that should have been followed. (And this is why I *hate* having Meta handle these. Too many FGITW responses.) I have no idea if anything potentially salvageable was missed now. But, I did look over the 4 questions with the [sqa] tag at this moment, and determined that none of them were useful. So I deleted them. [[meta-tag:status-completed]]

Comment: @CodyGray:  There wasn't much there.  What could be saved was, but there was maybe three or four out of them all.  We're all good.

Comment: There is also [tag:qa] tag

Comment: @VadimKotov:  Make a new burnination request for that one.