# The [qa] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Stack Overflow has a [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag (with the synonym [quality-assurance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-assurance)) with almost 1400 questions, out of which around 9% are closed.

From a quick look over the questions, there seems to be a bit of everything there - some good technical questions about frameworks and tools used for software testing (like Selenium or Cypress), some overly broad "how can I test XYZ" questions and even some questions about manual testing.

The technical questions should be considered on their own merit, and don't seem to gain anything from having the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag applied to them. At the end of the day, using Selenium to get the value of an element is a programming question, whether you're a software engineer, a QA engineer or a sparkly unicorn. Lumping these questions together under a single tag doesn't seem to serve any purpose.
As for the off-topic questions - they should be closed (and possibly deleted). Having such a tag may only encourage new users who aren't familiar with SO to think that they may be legitimate questions here.

To make a long story short - can we burninate the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag and its [quality-assurance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-assurance) synonym?

**EDIT #1:**
Following up on Braiam's comment regarding the close rate for this tag, Oleg Valter created an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1536512#resultSets). The query shows that more than 44% of the questions with this tag were deleted. If we take the deleted questions into account, almost 29% of them have been closed. IMHO, these numbers further support the case for removing this tag.

**EDIT #2:**
Following up on Oleg Valter's comment:

> For the general audience: the most important part to discuss is if there are valid questions tagged [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) but for which no other more specific tag applies (i.e. testing framework/methodology-specific)

I've created an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1536785/qa-questions-with-no-other-tags) for the question that have only the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag. At the point of writing this text, there are only 29 such questions, 14 of which are already closed.

I've gone over all the open questions, retagged two, and voted to close the others. In other words, I see no valid questions that have only the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag.

**EDIT #3:**
As suggested, an analysis of the [preliminary tests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/223467):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) does not describe the **contents** of the question - it describes, it very vague terms, **why** the question is asked ("in order to test a piece of software"). It does not, however, describe the **content** of the question - the question may be about testing some HTTP-based API, some desktop GUI, a library in Rust or what have you. All of these are valid scenarios to test ("to perform [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) on"), but all are wildly different. The presence of the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag does nothing to inform the reader on the content of the post. An extension of this notion is that searching by it (or excluding it) will also not yield any meaningful result.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Probably not. The tag defines [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) as "Quality assurance, or QA for short, is the systematic monitoring and evaluation of the various aspects of a project, service or facility to maximize the probability that minimum standards of quality are being attained by the production process". Generally speaking, I believe it's agreed that Stack Overflow focuses on the technical areas of how some task is achieved or problem solved, not the processes around them, which are probably better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Again, I believe it doesn't. As suggested in the linked MSE post, a good test is whether this tag is superfluous in most (or at least many) cases. Most of the on-topic questions with this tag, are about a specific technical issue (e.g., "How do I use Selenium to check XYZ"). For those type of questions, the tag is superfluous - the question is technical, and the reason some technology is used to achieve some goal is inconsequential.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   Not really. As noted above, [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) can mean a wide array of practices, from writing code to interface with a system, manually clicking on buttons and observing the responses, or even "humanly" evaluating if a certain flow is intuitive to a new user or not.

Comment: A [quick query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1536512#resultSets) does not show very promising stats overall: if we count deleted questions, nearly half of them get deleted, and nearly a third - closed

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356157/can-we-sqash-this-tag

Comment: QA is such a wide berth of topics, there's no reason to have it as a tag. Use framework-specific tags (e.g. [tag:selenium], [tag:pester], [tag:junit] etc.) instead. Asking about general QA practices is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, QA also refers to 'Question/Answer' and new users of the site may use it incorrectly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Progress:

The [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=qa),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqa%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqa%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqa%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqa%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=414992)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Unfortunately, someone rolled back the edit on their question with which the tag was removed, and so it reappeared. I already rolled back again, but now it seems that the tag turned into a zombie tag that is shown as a tag with 1 question even if there is no question anymore.

Comment: @jps Sigh, it's a stuck tag. We'll need a blacklist request to get rid of it

Comment: I was too pessimistic. It's gone now, despite the wrong number of questions displayed. Many others that should have gone too are still there.

Answer (score 19):

There's [a separate QA site](https://sqa.stackexchange.com) for a reason. I say kill this tag with fire.

Comment: Having a separate site is not grounds for burnination. There are Vi and Emacs sites out there, but those tags are still on topic for the site.

Comment: @BhargavRao the point is not about topicality, it's that you can have an entire site (I would say a science, and it isn't specific to software development) topic about it, hence it's super broad.

Comment: In this case I think a scope overlap between the SO and SQA sites can be phrased as: Technical, specific questions about various software testing issues belong on SO. Broader and more subjective topics seem to belong on the SQA site(?). Notably the SQA looks like it's in some early beta since the [on-topic](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is very poorly written - as it currently stands, nothing is on topic on that site... I don't think we can defer users to some beta site which is still struggling to decide what's on-topic 11 years after launch.

Comment: (Funny how the on-topic page of a quality site is of very poor quality and there are apparently no routines or concerns regarding how to maintain it...)

Comment: @Lundin But they do tell you what is on topic: questions related to testing. And the help center tells you exactly why such tag shouldn't exist, the topic is so big and touch so many things.