# Incorrectly filtering of new questions when viewing questions tagged with multiple tags

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search

Whenever picking a view with multiple tags, like in my case [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa), SO search syntax `[qa] [c++]`, new questions only tagged C++ keep popping up, even though they lack the [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qa) tag in this case.

I thought I'd help out with the tag burnination of the QA tag by focusing my efforts on areas where I have decent domain knowledge. And to do so I picked this search filter. But my efforts are disrupted as new posts not even using both tags but only the popular [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag keep popping up. Refreshing the browser view fixes it for a brief while, until someone asks or edits a question tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

This seems to be a fairly new bug since I haven't noticed it before.

Comment: I think this has been reported several times... time to go dupe hunting

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Yes it would surprise me if I'm the first to spot it. However, it's more work to find a dupe on meta than to post this. I even tried but gave up.

Comment: It has been broken like this forever for me. It gets rereported in different ways now and then. [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407628/newest-activity-for-2-or-more-tags-shows-questions-with-new-activity-when-the-ju) is one I could find.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407628/newest-activity-for-2-or-more-tags-shows-questions-with-new-activity-when-the-ju (bleugh, ninja'd)

Comment: Also it's really sad that nobody has fixed the bug if it's been around for over 2 years! This is a bug in the fundamental core behavior of the site: view content by picking tags.

Comment: On MSE: [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343767)

Comment: Related: *[The \[qa\] tag is being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414992/)*